# Puma server inside heroku container fails to connect to port

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dockerfile, puma, docker-container

I have a docker container: (called `Dockerfile.web`, relevant parts)

```
ARG PORT=3000
ENV PORT=$PORT

EXPOSE $PORT

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["rails", "server"]
```

Puma: `config/puma.rb`

```
before_fork do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.disconnect! if defined? ActiveRecord
end

on_worker_boot do
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection if defined? ActiveRecord
end

preload_app!
```

So when I run `heroku container:push web` followed by `heroku container:release web`, the app deploys, but the puma server doesn't come up b/c the port cannot be connected to:

```
Booting Puma
Rails 5.2.2 application starting in development 
Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
 Puma starting in cluster mode...
 * Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.6.0-p0), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
 * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
 * Environment: development
 * Process workers: 1
 * Preloading application
 * Listening on tcp://localhost:41626
 Use Ctrl-C to stop
 - Worker 0 (pid: 28) booted, phase: 0
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
Stopping process with SIGKILL
```

I'm following [the official guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server) but I haven't added the sections:

```
rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'
```

Where could my error be? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you left this part out:

```
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
```

You can't pick your own port. [Use the `$PORT` that Heroku gives you](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#dockerfile-commands-and-runtime).

Comment: tried that @Chris. Still the same error. I don't have a `Procfile` either. I don't suppose that is required when I have the `config/puma.rb` ?

Comment: Try taking `ENV PORT=$PORT` out of your `Dockerfile`. You shouldn't be setting that yourself.

Comment: good advice. unfortunately i still get the same error :(

When i do a `echo $PORT` on the attached dyno, the o/p is 54325, but the server startup log says `Listening on tcp://localhost:7058`. Could that difference in the port numbers be a cause?

Comment: What do you mean by "on the attached dyno"? Are you running a one-off dyno? It probably won't have the same `$PORT` as what your web dyno has. You might try logging `$PORT` when your web dyno starts up so you can compare better.

Comment: you're right. Logged the `$PORT`, it seems to be the same as the one that puma is listening to. Strange. I have raised an issue with Heroku support, as this seems like a specific issue. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

For people arriving here, the solution was to invoke the puma server directly from the docker `CMD` so that all the settings in the config file are applied. The reason is that on heroku, stuff like port is added dynamically, so container images (which are built out earlier) will not have those images. Somehow using the `$PORT` values inside Dockerfile also did not help. The solution was to do

```sh
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "puma", "-C", "config/puma.rb"]

# or if you prefer the bash style
CMD bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```